# How to undo 'exclude from project' in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, undo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undo VS 'Exclude from project'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352554/undo-vs-exclude-from-project)

I mistakenly chose the Exclude From Project menu item thinking I could choose what to exclude but it excluded the currently opened file.

I did not notice what file that was and there is no undo enabled.

How can I undo this operation?  How can I detect what file was excluded?  Is there some kind of log file?

Comment: I guess it is not under revision control, right?

Comment: Yes, it is imported port of large code base under smartSVN.  Which of the many files was inadvertently removed from the project build?

Comment: Is the project file under revision control? You should be able to see what has changed in your working copy. That said, I _think_ the project file is not saved until you build (or do something of a similar nature). If that describes your situation, closing Visual Studio may get you a dialog that asks if you want to save the project file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose "Add > Existing Item..." then add the files you have excluded

Comment: From the question: "I did not notice what file that was..."

Comment: Click Second icon "Show All files" From the Top Left of Solution Explorer Window. You win see.

Comment: DO NOT FOLLOW THIS ANSWER      On the top of the Solutions Explorer there is a "view all files" option... click that button. Then right click the objects and select include in project.

Comment: can you explain why not use the above option I think both the approaches achieves the same result.