# Not able to reference namespace from project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a few folders inside my interfaces sub project. I can "see" two of them, but not the third. The reference is obviously added, otherwise I wouldn't be able to "see" or access any of the namespaces inside the sub project.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

[image: missing namespace reference]

File **ProjectContext.cs** from project **Project.Data** needs to inherit an interface from another project **Project.Interfaces**.

**Project.Data** has a reference to **Project.Interfaces**.

The interface is located in **Project.Interfaces\Data\IProjectContext.cs**.

For whatever reason the **Data** directory is not visible in the autocomplete provided by Visual Studio. I am not able to access the **Project.Interfaces.Data** namespace.

`project.json` from **Project.Data**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
"Project.Interfaces": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
"System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.3.0"
},

"frameworks": {
"netstandard1.6": {
  "imports": "dnxcore50"
}
}
}
```

`ProjectContext.cs`

```
namespace Project.Data
{
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

}
}
```

`IProjectContext.cs`

```
namespace Project.Interfaces.Data
{
    interface IProjectContext
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the namespace inside the class file itself?

Comment: Provide more information. Did you referenced that project? your project.js (or csproj if you are on vs2017), platforms you target etc.

Comment: @Tseng You can see that I have autocomplete for two of those folders (Services and Repositories) so that means that yes, I have made a reference to project Interfaces from project Data.

Comment: @Steve The namespaces match the folder structure you can see.

Comment: A folder is not a namespace.  Are you certain there are classes within the `Data` folder that are in the right namespace?  Are those classes [included in the project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352554/undo-vs-exclude-from-project)?  Did they successfully compile?

Comment: @BurningHippo can you post a screenshot or code from one of the classes you are trying to reference?

Comment: I think one/more file that you are trying to reference is deleted or The file being referenced has been renamed.

Comment: The project builds with no errors. I will update the question with the files in question.

Comment: @BurningHippo: That wasn't my question. i.e. you have two projects (interfaces and repositories) so its not clear where the name space is defined. My question is still: Have you referenced all required projects. w/o project.json/*.csproj we cant be certain

Comment: @Tseng I added my project.json file, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default access modifier in c# is `internal`. Since your `IProjectContext` interface doesn't have a modifier, it is assumed to be `internal` and so not available to other projects.

Make the interface public and you will be able to reference it in other projects.

```
namespace Project.Interfaces.Data
{
    public interface IProjectContext
    {

    }
}
```

If you want the interface to be internal for API reasons, you can add an `InternalsVisibleTo` line to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in your `Project.Interfaces` project:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Project.Data")]
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have the impression that the folder structure defines the namespaces. They are in fact totally irrelevant (although it's a good convention to follow). Check your files inside the folders that are missing, and change the namespace definition in the code, presumably you want this to match  your folder structure.

Another thing to look for is whether the classes /interfaces are public.