# How to undo "Exclude From Project" in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I create ASP.NET Core 1.1 by Visual Studio 2019 Community. I exclude directory `wwwroot`,

[image]

then I don't know how to undo this action.

I try like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1352560/3728901 but context menu like this didn't exist.

How to undo "Exclude folder" in Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

do like this in Visual studio 2019

[image]

Comment: Also have a look at the .csproj file, it may contain old exclude/include statements.

Comment: FYI: this DID not work for me until I selected the actual folder (in my case Models) and then clicked Show All Files. Ten the excluded items appeared.

Answer (score 1):

In *solution explorer* click on the Project node and select *show all files* then right click wwwroot and select include